# Get url variable from request

Tags: django, django-views

One of my URLs looks like this:

```
url(r'^(?P<my_id>[0-9]+)/foo/', Foo.as_view()),
```

Given this CBV:

```
Class Whatever(View):

    @custom_decorator(my_id)
    def post(self, request, my_id):
        # ...
```

I need to access to **my_id** in the decorator. What is the best way to accomplish this?
Maybe, overriding **initial** and take it from **request.path**?

Comment: That post method takes optional arguments `post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):` You can print the `args` to get the my_id

Comment: Show us you `custom_decorator` code

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev https://github.com/jsocol/django-ratelimit/blob/master/ratelimit/decorators.py

Answer (score 0):

You should named your parameter in your URL :

```
url(r'^(?P<my_id>[0-9]+)/foo/', Foo.as_view()),
```

And then use it in your CBV :

```
Class Whatever(View):

@decorator(my_id)
def post(self, request, my_id, *args, **kwargs):
    self.kwargs['my_id']
    ...
```

Comment: NameError: name 'my_id' is not defined

Comment: My bad, use `self.kwargs['my_id']`. Don't forget to change the method signature : `def post(self, request, my_id, **kwargs):` I will update my answer.

Comment: But I won't be able to access to my_id in my custom decorator

Comment: What is the purpose of your `decorator`? Where did `decorator` comes from?

Comment: @RajaSimon It's a custom decorator

Comment: The decorator won't get the my_id in that way. You can extract it from func *args inside the decorator, but not as the decorator argument. Becasuse function decorates before launching and there won't be any my_id in that time.